# process < br/> in C#

Tags: c#, xml, html-agility-pack

I was trying to include space in output when processing xml in C#. Here's What I have

```
text = text.Replace("&lt;br /&gt;", " ");
text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text);
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(text);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
{
          sb.Append(' ');
           sb.AppendLine(node.InnerText);
}
<root><Paragraph>
<![CDATA[       Electrical Technologies]]>&lt;br /&gt;<![CDATA[Thomas Edison]]> </Paragraph></root>
```

I want the output to be `Electrical TechnologiesSPACEThomas Edison` but the output is `Electrical TechnologiesThomas Edison`.

Any suggestions.

Thanks
R

Comment: You may find this interesting: https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery. I think it's more convenient to use. Also `Selecting "div span" from the HTML5 spec (a 6 megabyte HTML file) is about 500 hundred times faster than HtmlAgilityPack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) converts `&lt;` and `&gt;` to `<` and `>`, you might try replacing with the HTML space character `&nbsp;` instead. I.e.

```
text = text.Replace("&lt;br /&gt;", "&nbsp;");
                                     ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Linq to Xml for parsing xml. Here is the way to extract CDATA values:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var values = xdoc.Root.Element("Paragraph").Nodes()
                 .OfType<XCData>()
                 .Select(x => x.Value.Trim());
```

If you want to get values of all CDATA nodes in this xml file:

```
var values = xdoc.DescendantNodes().OfType<XCData>().Select(x => x.Value.Trim());
```

This query returns two items:

```
[ "Electrical Technologies", "Thomas Edison" ]
```

You can format output as you wish. E.g. joining values with spaces in one string:

```
var result = String.Join(" ", values);
```